# Access elements generated after load?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use jQuery to setup a form validation, but theres this table that can have entries added to it *after* the page has loaded. But when I set up function to try and access them nothing happens. The first row in the table responds to the code but the ones generated after that remain unaffected. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to use the [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function, it allows elements added after the page load to be included.